# MVC Forms authentication breaks no longer functional after move to Server 2016

Tags: c#, ldap, forms-authentication, windows-server-2016, iis-10

I am working on an application transfer between Windows Server 2008R2 running IIS 7.5 into a Windows 2016 Server running IIS 10. The login system for the application is using Form Authentication with LDAP to allow the user to log in and make changes. The user can login without any issue on the 2008R2 server, creating the necessary cookie for usage. However, on the 2016 Server, the login system authentication seems to break. It seems as though the cookie is created but that the system does not seem to be able to find the user after the cookie is created. Furthermore, on a specific page that does not run any of the login processes, the application appears to be using Windows Authentication rather than the Forms Authentication that it is explicitly being told to use. The settings for the application in the web.config specifically tell it to use forms rather than windows authentication.

The web.config for the application contains the following information for the connection strings:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="ADConnectionString" connectionString="LDAP://OURLDAPSYSTEM"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

The LDAP item for this system is only used for validation not permissions.

and the authentication and membership:

```
<system.web>
  <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms name=".ADAuthCookie" loginUrl="~/" timeout="60" slidingExpiration="true" protection="All"/>
  </authentication>
  <membership defaultProvider="ADMembershipProvider">
    <providers>
      <add name="ADMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ADConnectionString" attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName"/>
    </providers>
  </membership>
</system.web>
```

In the controller that performs the login process:

```
userLoginSuccess = Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password);
//Make call to another DB to check permissions for usage
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, true);
```

On the IIS on the server, the authentication for the application appears as follows:
[Authentication for the application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZepGP.png)

While the authentication for the entire Web Site appears as follows: [Authentication for the Site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lz3XA.png)

Each of these match what is already located on the Windows 2008R2 server.

Anyone have any ideas what would have changed on the Windows 2016 server that would prevent the authentication from working the same as 2008R2? And if so, how would I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Same thing here - just spent all day looking at this.

Found this: https://www.itnota.com/enable-secure-httponly-cookies-iis/

```
<system.web>
  ...
  <httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="false" />
  ...
</system.web>
```

We added the  to the web.config and it worked.

Comment: Please include the solution as a code snippet instead of an image. Thank you.